# How to add something into a new row

Tags: jquery

What is suppose to happen is that the user types in their question and and select their answers and when they click on the "Add Question" button, then it will add the questions and answer.

Problem is that I can add an answer (you can test this in this fiddle, click [here](http://jsfiddle.net/YTh5Y/1/), the function to add the answer to a new table row is at the bottom where `function insertQuestion(form) function` is.
Example of selecting an answer: open grid and select button "4", type in 1 in number of answers textbox and select button "B", then click on "Add Question" button.  )

But when include this code in the `function insertQuestion(form) function` to try and add the question:

```
$('#question').each( function() {

    var $this = $(this);
    var $questionText = $("<textarea></textarea>").attr('name',$this.attr('name'))
               .attr('value',$this.attr('value'))
    $question.append($questionText);    

});
```

It would not add a row at all. It states `$("<textarea></textarea>").attr('name',$this.attr('name'))` is undefined in the console.

How can I get it so that it would add a question from the textarea into the row in another textarea?

My current code which is not working is in this jsFiddle, click [here](http://jsfiddle.net/YTh5Y/3/), the function which add rows is near bottom of javascript section.

Comment: Is there a missing link?

Comment: sorry, thanks for the spot, I have fixed the link

Comment: Use `.val()` to get/set a value instead of `.attr('value')`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`$('#question')` found a table with the id question, not an input. It doesn’t have a `name` or `value`.

So the value of `$this.attr('name')` is `undefined`. When you call `.attr` with an undefined second argument, it returns the value of the attribute. So…

```
$questionText = $(…).….attr('name', undefined)
```

…*gets* the value of the newly-created `$questionText`’s `name` attribute, which is also `undefined`. Then you try to call `.attr` on it, which throws the error.

**The solution should be to find `#questionTextArea` instead of `#question`.**

---

FWIW, there a couple of safer ways to set your attributes:

1. Use `||` to substitute the empty string:

   ```
   ….attr('name', $this.attr('name') || '');
   ```
2. Use a hash of attributes:

   ```
   ….attr({ name: $this.attr('name') });
   ```
3. Pass a hash of attributes into `$` (FYI, you don’t need to close the tag you pass into the jQuery function when you’re creating a element with no extra HTML. It translates it, internally, to `document.createElement('textarea')` either way):

   ```
   var $questionText = $("<textarea>", {
       name: $this.attr('name'),
       value: $this.attr('value')
   });
   ```

Comment: Ok I will text this in about 15 mins because I have a quick meeting to go to and then I will test your code, thank you :)